# How do I return a specific number of items from an API in react?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

The api that im pulling data from has 5000 records, im trying to pull on 20 for test purposes. I tried
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?=20 but i'm still getting the 5000. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=0&_limit=10

Comment: can you mark this answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try hitting the URL with below params

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=10